# CORS implementation IN Javascript

Tags: javascript, cors

I want to access a resource placed in someother server. I want to access it from javascript , I tried implementing CORS , by following tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) . But didn't get how to configure other server with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so still browser didnt allowed access  . I then tried installing CORS extension for chrome , it worked , but the issue with chrome extension is that , if I access any resource from the same server , where web page is hoisted , I get this error : The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values,  but only one is allowed. Origin *_* ,is therefore not allowed access.

In case of chrome extension cross domain resource access works but from same domain fails.
I want to implement CORS  through code , rather than extension .

Comment: does the other server also has the CORS header in the response it sends ? you can check that from Chrome's developer tools Network tab.

Comment: In javascript I have made the required CORSrequest , but on other server there is wamp , I am not able to figure out where to add below line : Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" . is it httpd.conf or any other file , I have added it in <Directory> but still when I try request , I get error  : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: By using CORS extension for chrome , Without making any configuration changes to other server , I get response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it :

1. Add the chrome extension CORS to chrome , then if you try to make a cross domain XMLHTTPRequest , the browser won't complain , it would load the cross domain resource.
2. If you dont want extension , other way is to configure the cross domain server.Below is the process for wamp server

   - open file apache/conf/httpd.conf and uncomment below line :

   > LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

   - Add below lines under "Directory" tag

     `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </IfModule>`

   Use * if you want to allow cross domain from all servers else give the name of server explicitly.
   Now save the httpd.conf file and restart the wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the two opetions mentioned by @Bhupendra, You could also run a proxy. The Proxy goes between your browser and the *actual* server, and adds the headers on the fly. For development, this is a perfectly fine solution.

Two node projects that i have used:

- https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere
- https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy

You will need node.js and npm for both.