# How can I load a three.js Blender 2.7 exported model without being on a HTTP server?

Tags: three.js

Hi I and currently doing all my THREE.js things on file:///.

When I follow tutorials to load models they do

```
var myLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

myLoader.load( url-path-to-file );
```

The error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/.../.../.../testmodel.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. three.js:11996
THREE.JSONLoader: "./testmodel.js" seems to be unreachable or the file is empty. three.js:11952
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/.../.../.../testmodel.js'.
```

Because of the limitations of using the file protocol I cannot load things like this. I am wondering how to skip this? I am thinking of storing the exported blender as a JavaScript object and then maybe there is already a piece of THREE.js that can do the rest for me?

Comment: you can implement cors in javascript :

see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690687/cors-implementation-in-javascript/24775860#24775860

Comment: use the chrome flag --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a python web server from your root directory is what I have done to avoid XSS related errors. I have python installed in windows.

Python version 3 in windows from directory that has your HTML file etc:

```
c:\Python33\python.exe -m http.server
```

then point your browser to:

```
http://localhost:8000/yourhtmlfile.html
```

For more info on running the server for various versions of python / OS see here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Not what I was looking for but I still agree that it's correct. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's kind of a pain, but I find ultimately the best way. Using the chrome flag --allow-file-access-from-files is also an option but I hate having to close down chrome and restart it, and also running a special chrome instance every time I want to develop, or even being forced to use chrome (or firefox which has an about:config option as well).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little project. It is a 3D file viewer and has the ability to load STL and Collada files locally in the client. Works both locally and on a server:

https://github.com/yomboprime/Visor3D

Deriving from the code a *local* JSON loader function is trivial. Yoy can start modifying the loadDAEFile() function (main.js), which reads local file as text.